# (fmap.fmap) for Applicative

Tags: haskell, applicative

`fmap.fmap` allows us to go "two layers deep" into a functor:

```
fmap.fmap :: (a -> b) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
```

Is this also possible for applicative functors? Let's say I wanted to combine `Just (+5)` and `[1,2,3]` by using their applicative properties. I can think of an obvious way to do it, but it doesn't seem that trivial to me.

`(<*>).(<*>)` doesn't a have a conclusive type signature:

```
((<*>).(<*>)) :: (a1 -> a2 -> b) -> ((a1 -> a2) -> a1) -> (a1 -> a2) -> b
-- where I would expect something like:
-- ((<*>).(<*>)) :: f (g (a -> b)) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
```

Is it possible to compose `Just (+5)` and `[1,2,3]` in this fashion?

EDIT:

The first step would be to go with either:

- `pure $ Just (+5)` and `fmap pure [1,2,3]`, or
- `fmap pure (Just (+5)` and `pure [1,2,3]`

But I still don't how to compose these...

EDIT:

It would be nice to have a general way to compose a function `f (g (a -> b)` and `f (g a)`, I'm not just looking for a solution for the above case, which is just supposed to serve as an example input of such a function. Basically I want a function:

```
(<***>) :: f (g (a -> b)) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
```

Comment: `f (g a)` is a nested functor. But what you have is two separate, unrelated functors. You'll have to convert one to the other.

Comment: It depends on what you want to get. A list of maybes?

Comment: Or a maybe list, doesn't really matter, see my edit

Comment: If you want to map a list to a list, you can use just its `Functor` instance, it doesn't have to be an `Applicative`. Thus you want a `fmap` on the list side, not a `<*>`. You also want to insert `pure` in there somewhere to get `Just Integer` from `Integer`. `fmap ((<*>) (Just (+5)) . pure) [1,2,3]` does the job.

Comment: Another option would be to convert a Maybe to a List (this is specific to these types and cannot be generalised to any Applicative): `(maybeToList (Just (+ 5))) <*> [1,2,3]`.

Comment: While this works, in the end I want it general enough to apply `f (g (a -> b)` to `f (g a)`. And I don't see how I get there from this

Comment: If you want to apply `f (g (a -> b)` to `f (g a)` you may want to give a better example of it in the question. `Just (+5)` and `[1,2,3]` are not of these types.

Comment: https://ideone.com/o1KI3u

Comment: @n.m. My first edit gives you `f (g a)` from those. But the function that you provided is just what I looked for.

Comment: This is basically just `(<*>) . fmap (<*>)`

Answer (score 4):

`liftA2` has a similar compositional property as `fmap`.

```
liftA2 f            ::    f a  ->    f b  ->    f c
(liftA2 . liftA2) f :: g (f a) -> g (f b) -> g (f c)
```

So you can write

```
(liftA2 . liftA2) ($) (pure (Just (+5))) (fmap pure [1,2,3]) :: [Maybe Integer]
```

i.e., `(<***>) = (liftA2 . liftA2) ($)`. (much like `(<*>) = liftA2 ($)`)

---

Another way to look at it is that the composition of applicative functors is an applicative functors, this is made concrete by [`Data.Functor.Compose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, PartialTypeSignatures #-}

import Data.Functor.Compose
import Data.Coerce

(<***>) :: forall f g a b. (Applicative f, Applicative g)
        => f (g (a -> b)) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
(<***>) = coerce ((<*>) :: Compose f g (a -> b) -> _)
```

The point with `coerce` is to show that `(<***>)` *is* the applicative `(<*>)` for the right type; we can also do the unwrapping manually

```
f <***> x = getCompose $ Compose f <*> Compose x
```

Answer (score 2):

We have a `f (g (a->b))`. To get `g a -> g b` from `g (a->b)` we just need `<*>`, but `g (a->b)` is wrapped in `f`. Luckily `f` is a Functor so we can `fmap` over it.

```
Prelude> :t fmap (<*>)
fmap (<*>)
  :: (Functor f1, Applicative f) =>
     f1 (f (a -> b)) -> f1 (f a -> f b)
Prelude>
```

That's better, we have a function wrapped in a Functor now. If this Functor happens to be an Applicative, we can apply `<*>` through it.

```
Prelude> :t (<*>) . fmap (<*>)
(<*>) . fmap (<*>)
  :: (Applicative f, Applicative f1) =>
     f1 (f (a -> b)) -> f1 (f a) -> f1 (f b)
Prelude>
```

Just what the doctor ordered.

```
Prelude> let (<***>) = (<*>) . fmap (<*>)
Prelude> [Just (+2), Just (*3), Nothing] <***> [Just 7, Just 42, Nothing]
[Just 9,Just 44,Nothing,Just 21,Just 126,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing]
Prelude>
```